# sed regex with multiple matches and condition

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to convert strings like:

```
abc=123.24|127.9|2891;xyz;hgy
```

to:

```
abc=123.24,127.9,2891;xyz;hgy
```

This is close:

```
echo "abc=123.24|127.9|2891;xyz;hgy" | sed -r 's/(=)([0-9.]+)\|/\1\2,/g'
```

but returns:

```
abc=123.24,127.9|2891;xyz;hgy
```

How can I do the rest of the numbers in a similar fashion if the number of bar-separated numbers is variable?

**Clarification**:

I hate it when people do not give me the whole picture in questions, but my original description above did just that.  The small example is embedded in a much larger line that includes "|" separated text.  I want to replace only the "|" with "," between numbers that follow an equal sign.  Here is an entire line as an example:

```
chr1    69511   rs75062661  A   G   .   QSS_ref ASP;BaseCounts=375,3,118,4;CAF=[0.348,0.652];COMMON=1;EFF=NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|Aca/Gca|T141A|305|OR4F5|protein_coding|CODING|ENST00000335137|1|1);GNO;HRun=0;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;KGPROD;KGPhase1;LowMQ=0.0280,0.0580,500;MQ=49.32;MQ0=14;MSigDb=ACEVEDO_METHYLATED_IN_LIVER_CANCER_DN,KEGG_OLFACTORY_TRANSDUCTION,REACTOME_GPCR_DOWNSTREAM_SIGNALING,REACTOME_OLFACTORY_SIGNALING_PATHWAY,REACTOME_SIGNALING_BY_GPCR,chr1p36;NORMALT=86;NORMREF=228;NSM;NT=het;OTHERKG;QSS=8;QSS_NT=6;REF;RS=75062661;RSPOS=69511;S3D;SAO=0;SGT=AG->AG;SOMATIC;SSR=0;TQSS=1;TQSS_NT=2;TUMALT=15;TUMREF=227;TUMVAF=0.06198347107438017;TUMVARFRACTION=0.1485148514851485;VC=SNV;VLD;VP=0x050200000a05140116000100;WGT=1;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_AC=1424;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_AF=0.652014652014652;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_AFR_AC=162;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_AFR_AF=0.32926829268292684;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_AMR_AC=235;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_AMR_AF=0.649171270718232;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_ASN_AC=500;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_ASN_AF=0.8741258741258742;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_EUR_AC=527;dbNSFP_1000Gp1_EUR_AF=0.6952506596306068;dbNSFP_29way_logOdds=4.1978;dbNSFP_29way_pi=0.1516:0.0:0.6258:0.2226;dbNSFP_ESP6500_AA_AF=0.544101;dbNSFP_ESP6500_EA_AF=0.887429;dbNSFP_Ensembl_geneid=ENSG00000186092;dbNSFP_Ensembl_transcriptid=ENST00000534990|ENST00000335137;dbNSFP_FATHMM_score=0.51;dbNSFP_GERP++_NR=2.31;dbNSFP_GERP++_RS=1.15;dbNSFP_Interpro_domain=GPCR|_rhodopsin-like_superfamily_(1)|;dbNSFP_LRT_Omega=0.000000;dbNSFP_LRT_pred=N;dbNSFP_LRT_score=0.000427;dbNSFP_MutationAssessor_pred=neutral;dbNSFP_MutationAssessor_score=-1.295;dbNSFP_MutationTaster_pred=N;dbNSFP_MutationTaster_score=0.000162;dbNSFP_Polyphen2_HDIV_pred=B;dbNSFP_Polyphen2_HVAR_pred=B;dbNSFP_SIFT_score=0.950000;dbNSFP_Uniprot_aapos=141;dbNSFP_Uniprot_acc=Q8NH21;dbNSFP_Uniprot_id=OR4F5_HUMAN;dbNSFP_aaalt=A;dbNSFP_aapos=189|141;dbNSFP_aaref=T;dbNSFP_cds_strand=+;dbNSFP_codonpos=1;dbNSFP_fold-degenerate=0;dbNSFP_phyloP=0.267000;dbNSFP_refcodon=ACA;dbSNPBuildID=131   AU:CU:DP:FDP:GU:SDP:SUBDP:TU    228,232:3,3:322:4:86,109:0:0:1,2    227,228:0,0:244:1:15,16:0:0:1,2
```

The replacement in this line is of the string:

```
dbNSFP_aapos=189|141
```

with:

```
dbNSFP_aapos=189,141
```

Comment: Are you stuck with `sed`?

Comment: Nope.  However, I was trying to do this "inline" via pipes to avoid having to track another script in the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative, you can try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and its evalutation flag:

```
echo "..." | perl -pe 's{=([\d.|]+)}{"=" . (join ",", split /\|/, $1)}eg'
```

It searches for a string after an equal sign, splits it with `|` and join it with commas.

Answer (score 2):

why not:

```
sed 's/|/,/g'


kent$ echo "abc=123.24|127.9|2891;xyz;hgy"|sed 's/|/,/g'
abc=123.24,127.9,2891;xyz;hgy
```

Comment: Why not? Because people tend to think overly complicated when it comes to regexes :) +1 because you were a couple of seconds faster than me

Comment: Or because the OP did not give you the complete question--sorry.  See the clarification above.

Comment: @seandavi could you pls give a complete example line?

Comment: @Kent: added a full example line to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Without using perl you can use

```
input="abc=123;def=hello123test;dbNSFP_aapos=189|141|142;dbNSFP_aaref=T;another=test|hello;"

sed -r 's/(.*=)([0-9.]+\|)+(.*)/\1'$(sed -r 's/(.*=)([0-9.]+\|)+(.*)/\2/' <<< $input | tr '|' ,)'\3/' <<< $input
```

Output:

```
abc=123;def=hello123test;dbNSFP_aapos=189,141,142;dbNSFP_aaref=T;another=test|hello;
```

Replace `<<< $input` with your file or whatever you actually have as input :)

Explanation:

We have three capturing groups in the regex (I restructured the groups from the OP), the second will contain only the string where the replacement of the `|` is to happen, while the first and third contain everything before and after the second group.
See the [demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lZ4lS9).

Within the second command (`$(...)`) we grab the second capturing group with sed and replace every `|` inside with a comma. This substitution is then used to be put in the place of the second group within the other `sed`-call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming semicolon is your field separator, how about something like

```
tr `;\n' '\n;' | sed '/=[0-9.|]*$/s/|/,/g' | tr '\n;' ';\n'
```

This has a serious flaw; it fails in weird ways for the first and last fields on a line. If you can't live with that, maybe try this:

```
awk -F ';' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /=([0-9.]+\|)+[0-9.]+$/) gsub(/\|/,",",$i); print }'
```

Comment: you missed an end "/" in the compare condition. `($i ~ /=([0-9.]+\|)+[0-9.]+$/) `

Answer (score 0):

Using `tr`

```
echo "abc=123.24|127.9|2891;xyz;hgy" | tr \| ,
abc=123.24,127.9,2891;xyz;hgy
```